# Javascript - Setters y getters

Tags: javascript, objeto

Un setter y un getter se pueden establecer de esta forma:

```
//Un ejemplo de getter
Object.defineProperty (Number.prototype, 'Duplo', { get: function () {
    return this * 2
} })
```

Y se implementa de esta forma:

```
let X = 3 //Puede ser cualquier valor numérico
console.log (X.Duplo) //En este caso mostraría 6
```

Mi pregunta:
¿Existe alguna forma nativa de establecer setters y getters de esta forma (o como implementarla si no existiera)?

```
//El getter anterior
Number.prototype.getters.Duplo = function () {
    return this * 2
}
```

Algo así como que en Object.prototype existieran dos setters llamados "setters" y "getters" capaces de recibir cualquier propiedad (equivalente al MutationObserver para el DOM).

Comment: Aparentemente no es posible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Tu conoces una forma de crear los get/set, pero quieres hacerlo de otra manera, que sabes que no se puede. Entonces deberías explicar los motivos, ya que cualquiera podría dar una solución alternativa y esta no podría servirte.

Comment: Mi motivo es simple: elegancia del código. Lo más cercano que se me ocurrió fue mediante una función: Number.prototype.setter (NombrePropiedad, Callback). Implemente esta funcion y funciona perfectamente, pero sería más elegante si fuera al estilo de notacion de objetos: Number.prototype.setters.NombrePropiedad = Callback. Si no existe nativamente, ¿se pudiera emular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de indagar un poco en Google encontré la solución ideal. Usando Proxy:

```
Object.defineProperty (Object.prototype, 'getters', { get: function () {
let Esto = this
return new Proxy ({}, { set: (_, Clave, Fn) => Object.defineProperty (Esto, Clave, { get: function () { return Fn (this) } }) })
} })
```

Y para establecer un getter:

```
Number.prototype.getters.Duplo = E => E * 2
//Mucho más compacto que Number.prototype.getters.Duplo = function () { return this * 2 }
```

Y la implementación:

```
let X = 55
console.log (X.Duplo)
console.log ((10).Duplo)
```